# Getting data in a text file after updating it on highcharts but initially retrieving from csv file

Tags: php, javascript, file, highcharts

I am actually trying to do exactly what has been done in this example "http://jsfiddle.net/BrLp7/" but unfortunately not able to perform this task when retrieving data from csv file. Below is my code which doesn't output anything and when we click on a point in a given example the resulting graph has to be stored in some text file in this form 5,10,13 if last point was clicked.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "BasicForm.php">

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"   

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>Highcharts Example</title>

<!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->

<script type="text/javascript"   

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/excanvas.compiled.js"></script>

<![endif]-->

<!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

var options = {

chart: {

renderTo: 'container',

defaultSeriesType: 'line'

},
title: {
text: 'Input'
},
xAxis: {
categories: []
},
yAxis: {
title: {
text: 'Units'
}
},
plotOptions: {
series: {
cursor: 'pointer',
point: {
events: {
click: function() {                                                                                                                                                         

$.get('testFile.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');

$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {

var x=this.series.processedXData.indexOf(this.x);
var items = line.split(',');                                                                                              

seriesData =[];                                                                                                     

$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
if (itemNo < x) {
seriesData.push(parseFloat(item));
}  else if (itemNo == x){
seriesData.push(0);
}
});
}
this.series.setData(seriesData);

}
}
}
},
series: []

};

$.get('testFile.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
var lines = data.split('\n');

$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {

var items = line.split(',');

var series = {
data: []
};

$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {

series.data.push(parseFloat(item));    });

options.series.push(series);

});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<!-- 3. Add the container -->

<div id="container" style="width: 1400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
</FORM>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `2 body` tags in `1 document`; unformatted javascript; no actual question. I'm failing to see where I can help here.

Comment: Please refactor your code, which has incorrect structure. I advice to prepare appropriate html document.